# $A$ has property of Baire if and only if $A=B \sqcup Q$ where $B$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set and $Q$ is of first category

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, baire-category

Over $\Bbb{R}$, A set $A$ with a property of Baire is defined in our notes as the symmetric difference $A=G\triangle Q$ where $G$ is open and $Q$ is of first category. I am asked to show that a set $A$ has property of Baire **if and only if** $A=B \sqcup Q$ where $B$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set and $Q$ is of first category.

I can show that for $A=G\triangle Q$ with open $G$ and first-category $Q$, one gets $N=\overline{G}\setminus G$ is closed (and nowhere dense), and $N\triangle Q$ is of first category, hence $A={\overline{G}\triangle N \triangle Q}=\overline{G}\triangle (N \triangle Q)$ which means it is also a symmetric difference of closed set and a first category set. But for the countable intersection of open sets $B=\bigcap B_i$, I am not sure what to do similar to the above method. Is $B$ nowhere dense? If so, then $A $ is a first category set, but is it still the symmetric difference between an open set and a first-category set? I am not sure what to say about such $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Q$ is of first category, then for any closed $F$ such that $Q\subseteq F$, then $F\cap Q \subseteq Q$ is nowhere dense, and therefore $Q\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{Q_i}\cap F:=C$ and $C$ is $F_{\sigma}$. Now if $A=Q\triangle G $ where $G$ is open, $Q$ is contained in some $C$ like above, let's take $G\setminus C=G\setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{Q_i}\cap F=\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}{G\cap (Q_i\cap F)^c}$ and therefore $G\setminus C$ is $G_{\delta}$ set and is contained in $G$. $(G\setminus C)\cup (G\cap C)=G$, and $(G\setminus C)\triangle (G\cap C) \triangle (C\cap Q )$ satisfies: $G\setminus C$ is $G_{\delta}$, and  $(G\cap C) \triangle (C\cap Q )=(G\triangle Q)\cap C$ is of first category, and is also disjoint to $G\setminus C$.